# implement unix pipes in haskell

Tags: unix, haskell, pipe

I'm writing a mini shell and although I've got most of it planned out, one thing I'm not sure how to do is implement piping the output of one program as the input of another. Is there a sample or something that can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RWH Book has a complete example of how to emulate piping in Haskell, IMO is one of the best examples of the book and it could be quite enlightening.

=> http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/systems-programming-in-haskell.html#systems.piping

Good Luck.

Comment: Ah, I knew about real world haskell, but I didn't know there was a chapter on systems programming, thanks!